# Sorting C linked list in ASMx64 language

Tags: c, assembly, linked-list, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to create a function that sorts a C linked list in assembly, but it doesn't work, I don't see how I can resolve this problem, I've been on it for hours, if anyone could help it would be nice.
So the prototype of the function I'm trying to create is:

```
void ft_list_sort(t_list **begin_list, int (*cmp)());
```

The linked list I'm working on is just a simple basic list:

```
typedef struct s_list {
    void            *data;
    struct s_list   *next;
} t_list;
```

Here is my assembly code for the function with comments:

```
global ft_list_sort

section .text
ft_list_sort:
    mov r8,  [rdi]              ;put begin pointer in r8
    mov r10, rsi                ;put cmp function in r10

main_loop:
    cmp  r8,  0                 ;check if current list is null
    je   exit                   ;if null we are at the end of list so exit
    mov  r9,  [r8 + 8]          ;put current list -> next in r9
    push r9                     ;save the value in the stack
    jmp  sort_loop              ;jump to our second loop

main_loop_after:
    pop  r8                     ;current list = current list -> next
    jmp  main_loop

sort_loop:
    cmp  r9,  0                 ;check if loop list is null
    je   main_loop_after        ;if null we are at the end of list so jump back in main loop
    mov  rdi, [r8]              ;put current list data in rdi
    mov  rsi, [r9]              ;put loop list data in rsi
    call r10                    ;call cmp function
    cmp  rax, 0                 ;check the result
    ja   swap                   ;if above zero jump to swap

sort_loop_after:
    mov  rdx, [r9 + 8]
    mov  r9,  rdx               ;loop list = loop list -> next
    jmp  sort_loop              ;go back to begin of loop

swap:
    mov  rdx, rdi
    mov  rdi, rsi               ;swap rsi and rdi (current list data and loop list data)
    mov  rsi, rdx
    jmp  sort_loop_after        ;go back to the loop

exit:
    ret
```

And I'm running the function with this main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct s_list 
    void            *data;
    struct s_list   *next;
} t_list;

void                ft_list_push_front(t_list **begin_list, void *data);
int                 ft_list_size(t_list *begin_list);
void                ft_list_sort(t_list **begin_list, int (*cmp)());

t_list *lstnew(void *data) {
    t_list *newlist = malloc(sizeof(t_list));

    if (!newlist)
        return (NULL);
    newlist->data = data;
    newlist->next = NULL;
    return (newlist);
}

void lst_disp(t_list *lst) {
    while (lst) {
        printf("%d\n", (int)lst->data);
        lst = lst->next;
    }
}

void lst_clear(t_list **lst) {
    t_list *head = (*lst)->next;
    while (*lst) {
        free(*lst);
        *lst = head;
        if (head)
            head = head->next;
    }
}

int int_comp(void *n1, void* n2)
{
    return ((int)n1 - (int)n2);
}

int main(void) {
    t_list *list = lstnew((void*)1);
    ft_list_push_front(&list, (void*)10); //This function is to add a member to the list
    ft_list_push_front(&list, (void*)3);
    ft_list_push_front(&list, (void*)20);
    ft_list_push_front(&list, (void*)5);
    ft_list_push_front(&list, (void*)42);
    printf("before\n");
    lst_disp(list);
    printf("after\n");
    ft_list_sort(&list, &int_comp);
    lst_disp(list);
    lst_clear(&list);
    return (0);
}
```

It doesn't crash, but the function does nothing.
Output:

```
before
42
5
20
3
10
1
after
42
5
20
3
10
1
```

I tried to print the values of `(int)n1 - (int)n2` in my `int_comp` function and it segfaults so I'm guessing there's something wrong in `swap:` with the registers values but I don't know what, thanks for the help.
For the compilation I use a makefile because I'm compiling it along with other functions as a library.
so in order for just this file:

```
nasm -f elf64 ft_list_sort.s
ar rcs libasm_bonus.a ft_list_sort.o
gcc main.c libasm_bonus.a
```

If you want to see the makefile I pushed [my entire project on github](https://github.com/2LeoCode/libasm).

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't help us, it's not a technical diagnostic. Dump this into your debugger and step through to see what's wrong.

Comment: Tip: Look at the assembly output of some known-good C code for inspiration.

Comment: Can you please integrate your header file into the main program? And give exact compilation, assembly and linking sequence?

Comment: Did you try to step through the assembly code in a debugger?

Comment: @einpoklum edited (the list_sort file is in src_bonus on my github)

Comment: @user58697 i'm using lldb but i'm not very comfortable with debuggers I don't know how to go through the code step by step especially in assembly I just know how to see where it crashes when it does

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your function that you actually write to memory, i.e. no `mov [xxx], yyy`, so the list in memory is thus not changed at all.  Your `swap` moves around some registers but doesn't actually touch the structure of the list.

Comment: @Fayeure: Then learning how to do that is priority #1. It's not hard, but trying to do anything in assembly without knowing how to single step will make the development process drastically slower and more frustrating.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Thanks, but before swapping the register I put memory value into them, (mov rdi, [r8] and mov rsi, [r9]) isn't that the same?

Comment: @Fayeure: No, it is not.  The registers contain copies of those values, not references to them, and manipulating the values in the registers does not have any effect on memory.  If you want memory to change you have to store, e.g. by doing `mov [r8], rdi` after getting the desired new value into `rdi`.

Comment: As a C analogy, consider `long rdi; long *r8; rdi = *r8; rdi = 17; print(*r8);`.  This will not set `*r8` to `17`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! I didn't know that, I thought I could do this.

Answer (score 1):

As @NateEldridge notes, your assembly code doesn't ever actually write anything to memory.

It seems the heart of the problem is with this part:

```
swap:
    mov  rdx, rdi
    mov  rdi, rsi               ;swap rsi and rdi (current list data and loop list data)
    mov  rsi, rdx
    jmp  sort_loop_after        ;go back to the loop
```

Instead of swapping nodes of the list, in memory (which is what you seem to want to do, since you invoke this when the `cmp` function indicates the wrong order) - this swaps values in registers.